# by iterating I need to filter specific word using javascript, but I am not getting the expected value?

Tags: javascript

I need to filter the category type only but instead my code is returning the defined string.
My expected output is: funiture sofa galley.

```js
var contextstr =
  'Lorem Ipsum is category:funiture dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since category:sofa 1500s, when an unknown printer took a category:galley of type and scrambled it to make a type';

var count = 0;
while (true) {
  var findpos = contextstr.indexOf('category:', count);
  if (findpos == -1) break;
  var startpos = findpos + 9;
  var endpos = contextstr.indexOf(' ', startpos);
  var printcat = contextstr.substring(startpos + endpos);
  document.write(printcat + '<br>');
  //x++;
  count = endpos + 1;
}
```

Comment: what is the desired output you want?

Comment: from the variable string contextstr; my expected output shoulde be : funiture sofa galley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
var printcat = contextstr.substring(startpos + endpos);
```

to:

```
var printcat = contextstr.substring(startpos,endpos);
```

```js
var contextstr =
    
'Lorem Ipsum is category:funiture dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since category:sofa 1500s, when an unknown printer took a category:galley of type and scrambled it to make a type';
var x = 1;
var count = 0;
while (x=1) {
  var findpos = contextstr.indexOf('category:', count);
  if (findpos == -1) break;
  
  var startpos = findpos + 9;
  var endpos = contextstr.indexOf(' ', startpos);
  
  var printcat = contextstr.substring(startpos, endpos);
  
 document.write(printcat + '<br>');
  //x++;
  count = endpos + 1;
}
```

Comment: be sure to accept the answer that works best for you.  I thought your code was fine and you just had a minor issue with the substring function

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var contextstr =
  'Lorem Ipsum is category:funiture dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since category:sofa 1500s, when an unknown printer took a category:galley of type and scrambled it to make a type';

var splitArray = contextstr.split("category:");
splitArray.shift(); //Remove first item (Stuff right before first 'category:')
splitArray.forEach(split => {
  document.write(split.split(" ")[0] + '<br>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const contextstr =
  'Lorem Ipsum is category:funiture dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since category:sofa 1500s, when an unknown printer took a category:galley of type and scrambled it to make a type';

const matches = [...contextstr.matchAll(/(?<=category:)\S+/g)];

document.write(`${matches.join('\n')}<br>`);
```

## Explanation of `/(?<=category:)\S+/g`

```
/
  (?<=         positive lookbehind
    category:  matches anything with category: before it
  )            end of positive lookbehind
  \S           matches anything that's not a whitespace character
    +          ...if there are one or more of them
/g             global flag: match multiple times
```

Answer (score 0):

can you give this a try  ??

```
var contextstr =
  'Lorem Ipsum is category:funiture dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since category:sofa 1500s, when an unknown printer took a category:galley of type and scrambled it to make a type';

var pos = 0;
var printcat = '';
while (pos = contextstr.indexOf('category:')) {

  contextstr = contextstr.substring(pos+9);
  let cat = contextstr.substring(0, contextstr.indexOf(' '));
  contextstr = contextstr.substring(cat.length+1);
  printcat += cat + "<br>";

}
document.write(printcat);
```